# Ionic life cycle ionViewdidEnter not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an `ionic 2` app. It has a tab inside tab view. There are two tabs. `Home` and `Feed`. The `Feed` page has two new tabs , `Users` and `Freinds`. The root of `Feed` is `Users` page and `Users` page has an `ionViewDidEnter` method.

The problem I am facing is with this method not firing when I toggle between the parent tabs `Home` and `Feed`. If I toggle between `Users` and `Friends` it works. Otherwise only the life cycles in parent components work.

How can I solve this issue? Is there any work around to quickly fix this?

```
export class TabsPage {
  tab1Root: any = FeedPage;
  tab2Root: any = HomePage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , public auth: Authentication , public book: Bookemon) {}
}
```

`tabs.html`

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="home" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="feed" tabIcon="compass"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The seconds tabs are in `FeedPage`

```
export class FeedPage {
  tab1root = UsersPage;
  tab2root = FriendsPage;
  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController ) {}
  ionViewDidEnter () {
    // console.log('ran');
  }
}
```

feed.html

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="users" tabIcon="bonfire"  ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="freinds" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

users.ts

```
export class UsersPage {
  constructor( public navCtrl: NavController ) {}
  ionViewDidEnter () {
    console.log('ran');
    // not running when toggling between ``feed`` and ``home``
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more insight about your code?

Comment: can you share html? how are you adding Users and Friends tabs?

Comment: I have added the relevant code

Comment: You can use the `ionSelect` event to do something when each tab is selected: `<ion-tab (ionSelect)="yourMethod()"></ion-tab>`; maybe each time the parent tabs are selected, we can see which sub tabs are selected and execute some logic if needed. I don't know if this make sense in the context of your app. If you want I can add an answer with further information.

Comment: is there a way to initiate a ``pageload`` of users page with the ``yourMethod`` ? Essentially to initiate ``ionViewDidEnter``. An answer would be much appreciated.