# constructor not being called on first click - ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 tabs template to create an app. I would like to call the code written in constructor every time user taps on one of the tabs. However, this is not happening at the moment on first click. But when I do the second click, the constructor code is called normally. Any idea why?

```
export class HomePage {

    data = {};

    constructor(public http: Http,
                public navCtrl: NavController,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private storage: Storage,
    ) {

        this.storage.get('email')
            .then((val) => {
            console.log(val);
                if(val === null) {
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
                }
            });
    }
    }
}
```

**Logout function**

```
logout() {
        this.storage.remove('email')
            .then((val) => {
                console.log('logged out successfully!');
            })
    }
```

Ionic Info:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 ios 4.1.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.10.0
OS         : OS X El Capitan
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
npm        : 4.2.0
```

Comment: I think you are at the wrong place to add this click event code, you should check tab ts instead. Sometimes, when you switch home page to another, it may not release in memory thus homepage constructor doesn't run when you switch back.

Comment: so you want to retrieve it whenever you enter this page?

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 I did replace HomePage with TabsPage but still no luck.

Comment: @suraj Yes that would be great.

Comment: @PHPDev check my answer

Comment: You should provide your ionic info, try upgrade to the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside **`ngOnInit`**

```
export class HomePage  implements OnInit {
    data = {};
    constructor(public http: Http,
                public navCtrl: NavController,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private storage: Storage,
    ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('email')
            .then((val) => {
            console.log(val);
                if(val === null) {
                    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work! Same behaviour. It's taking me to login page ONLY upon second click on Home tab.

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

Use Ionic [`NavController`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) lifecyclehook - `ionViewDidEnter` or `ionViewCanEnter` if it is for login check only.

ionViewDidEnter:

> Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

ionViewCanEnter (NavGuard):

> Runs before the view can enter. This can be used as a sort of "guard" in authenticated views where you need to check permissions before the view can enter

```
export class HomePage {

    data = {};

    constructor(public http: Http,
                public navCtrl: NavController,
                private authService: AuthService,
                private storage: Storage,
    ) {}

    ionViewCanEnter(){
         return this.storage.get('email')
            .then((val) => {

            console.log(val);
            return val;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the same issue again. Works for the first time when the application loads. But when I log out for the second time, the home page access is still granted (instead of redirecting to login page).

Comment: is it logging your val?

Comment: yes for the first time but not for the second time :D. To be able to get the desired result, I have to re-tap on home page tab to see the login page. It seems (I dont know why) that nothing in homepage.ts is called upon first tap. But works fine on second tap.

Comment: tried other lifecyclehooks? `ionViewDidEnter` `ionViewWillEnter`?

Comment: strangely, all of them are behaving exactly the same way. null is returned in first attempt when the application first loads. But when I logout and login within the application, for some reason I have to re-tap the home page for null to return successfully.

Comment: maybe the issue is with your logout function.. can you add that to the question? are you getting a value before retapping?

Comment: logout function is working correctly, that's the reason it's giving me 'null', when it's logged OUT. When it is logged IN successfully, it gives me my email address (with which I logged in)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091621/ionic-life-cycle-ionviewdidenter-not-working

Comment: Thanks. I will be replying at both of these links once I manage to find the solution of this mysterious problem.

Comment: good luck :) It should have been resolved.. it does look like a critical bug in ionic itself